# jQuery scroll to bottom animation speed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm just playing around with the front-end jQuery aspects of a forum application (I'm much more suited to the back end - this is a very small  foray into the front end world of template + js creation).

Essentially, for every new comment the chat box container automatically scrolls to the bottom, showing the users the most recent message. The following code I'm using to achieve this is:

The chat-messages id is within the chat-box id container, css for both:

```
#chat-box {
  overflow: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 91vh;
}
#chat-messages {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 91vh;
}
```

To these, I am applying the following animation:

```
$('#chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() + $('#chat-messages').height()}, "slow");
```

A condensed version of function used when the submission event is triggered is:

```
function submitChatMessageEvent( event ) {
   console.log($('#btn-chat-input').val());
   $(chatMessageBlock).hide().appendTo("#chat-messages").fadeIn(1000);
   $('#chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() + $('#chat-messages').height()}, 8000);
}
```

The animation does what I want it too - that is, ensure the chat box is always showing the most recent chat at the bottom of the chat box. However - to the above animation the "slow" aspect does not work at all...? Any pro-tips on auto-scrolling to the bottom of a div with overflow on.

My thoughts are that I need to create the divider box - but somehow hide it first, then trigger the scrolling effect whilst simultaneously fading in the newly created comment...but I need some pointers if this is the correct method!

Comment: ...and you expect us to picture the animations in our heads, while guessing what your markup looks like, correct? To translate it in your terms, it's pretty much like someone showing you the results of a query and asking to modify it without showing you the SQL or the table structure. Consider adding a [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be working fine with the info you provided.

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower
>   animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be
>   supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds,
>   respectively.
>   http://api.jquery.com/show/

```js
var chatMessageBlock = $('#chat-block');

function submitChatMessageEvent( event ) {
    $(chatMessageBlock).hide().appendTo("#chat-messages").fadeIn(200 /* fast */);
    $('#chat-messages').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height() + $('#chat-messages').height()
    }, 600 /* 'slow' */);
}

submitChatMessageEvent();

$('#btn-chat-input').on('click',function(e){
  $('#chat-messages')[0].scrollTop = 0;
  submitChatMessageEvent(e);
});
```

```css
#chat-box {
  overflow: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 91vh;
}
#chat-messages {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 91vh;
}
p {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="btn-chat-input" value="Send" type="button"/>
<div id="chat-block" style="display:none">
  <p>One chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>My response</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Another chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Another chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>One last chat message</p>
</div>
<div id="chat-box">
  <div id="chat-messages"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rafael - will take a look at implement this, but yes, I'd like it to be slower and constantly hooked to the bottom of the "chat pile". Your solution seems to start again from the top - not good if we have 1000+ messages? :P

Comment: It's not a solution on how to scroll bottom. It's a demo to show the speed is working fine and the issue described in your question must be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `$('#chat-messages')[0].scrollTop = 0;` from your click event.

```js
var chatMessageBlock = $('#chat-block');

function submitChatMessageEvent( event ) {
    $(chatMessageBlock).hide().appendTo("#chat-messages").fadeIn(200 /* fast */);
    $('#chat-messages').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height() + $('#chat-messages').height()
    }, 600 /* 'slow' */);
}

submitChatMessageEvent();

$('#btn-chat-input').on('click',function(e){
  submitChatMessageEvent(e);
});
```

```css
#chat-box {
  overflow: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 91vh;
}
#chat-messages {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 91vh;
}
p {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btn-chat-input" value="Send" type="button"/>
<div id="chat-block" style="display:none">
  <p>One chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>My response</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Another chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Another chat message</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>One last chat message</p>
</div>
<div id="chat-box">
  <div id="chat-messages"></div>
</div>
```